# What is application footprint and how to calculate it?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, operating-system

What does term "application footprint" means for application developed in C/C++. And how we can calculate C/C++ application footprint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the size in code, data and heap that the application needs. In linux, you can check the size of the "text" (code), "data" and "bss" with `size a.out` (replace a.out with whatever your application is called). There are similar tools for Windows.

As to the heap needs, it's more complex, as for example loading a full model of a Boeing 747 (every nut, rivet, bolt, seat and button on the "TV remote") into Autocad takes much more memory than the model of two bolts with corresponding nuts through two plates of some metal in the same Autocad system - same thing with loading the latest novel by Ken Follet into the word processor is clearly different from loading your letter to the water company to complain about the water leak in your street. But a rough estimate, using a typical use-case (e.g. a model of something small, but still sophisticated enough to be meaningful).

Comment: Thanks Mats, quite helpful